# How to calculate shortest binary number that contains all numbers in range 0...2^(N-1)?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have binary numbers in range 0...2^(N-1). I need to caclulate shortest possible binary number that contains each and every number from range above for N=8. Leading zeros acceptable.

```
Example for N=2:

numbers: 00 01 10 11
answer: 00110, because: 00110 
                        00
                         01
                           10
                          11
```

Comment: It's almost a De Bruijn sequence, but with a couple of bits copied because it's not cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for help. I will read about this.